# String compare against an element in a string vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, compare

I am trying to compare a string (ignoring case) against a specified element in a vector string (I don't want to see if the string exists anywhere in the vector, only if it exists at the specific index).

I have not been successful using a string compare as I normally would.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you've tried and the result you got.

Answer (score 0):

strnicmp( ... ) is your tool.  the 'n' is for limited length, and the 'i' is for case insensitive.  You just need to add the the specific index to the vector: `vector+pos` or `&vector[pos]`

```
int isKeyFoundAtPos( const char* key, const char* vector, int vPos) {

    if( vPos > strlen(vector) )  // if you want to be safe, check for this and deal with it.
        return -1;

    return 0 == strnicmp( key, vector+vPos, strlen(key) );
}
```

...

```
const char* myKey = "abc";
const char* myVector = "123abc456ABC";

isKeyFoundAtPos( myKey, MyVector, 3 ); // string found
isKeyFoundAtPos( myKey, MyVector, 9 ); // string also found
```

I wrote the wrapper routine as an example, but honestly I would just use `strnicmp()` directly.